# Layout Change Visibility

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, augmented-reality

I'm trying to develop an Augmented Reality aplication for Android using Metaio. But actually I've a problem.
 I want to make a little menu appear when the aplication recongize a marker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonBar123"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/TextoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onTextoButtonClick"
        android:text="Texto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onImagemButtonClick"
        android:text="Imagem" />


</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My layout is on a View and I don't know how to change the ButtonBar123 to visible in Java code. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get a reference to your `Layout`

```
LinearLayout buttonBar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonBar123);
```

then set the `visibility`

```
buttonBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

[Visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Comment: I´m doing it, but its not working....

`LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonBar1234);
     linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Maybe is something related with the code.

[link](http://pastebin.com/ZAGumidc)

Comment: Post where you are doing it. Also, indicate if you are getting any errors

Comment: I'm doing this

`LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonBar1234); linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

I've no errors, but the menu just don't appear.

http://pastebin.com/ZAGumidc

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint there to see if it makes it to that line? The problem could be something unrelated. Also, I don't know if it will work but you can try `linear.invalidate()` after you set the `visibility`

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout buttonBar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonBar123);
buttonBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```